# MySQL spatial data query

Tags: mysql, spatial

I'm trying to implement a zone table with a polygon in one of its fields. I will use this to later on check if a certain point is contained within the polygon.

I have implemented it to the best of my knowledge but after testing i found that certain point (close to, but outside of the polygon) are being returned when they shouldn't.

```
CREATE TABLE `zones` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `geom` geometry NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO zones (created_at, updated_at, name, `geom`)
VALUES (NOW(),NOW(), "Purmerend", PolygonFromText('POLYGON(( 
52.37811421553942 4.98779296875,
52.36637614192118 5.002899169921875,
52.381467377903476 5.04547119140625,
52.46688700596046 5.156707763671875,
52.62306005822956 5.04547119140625,
52.64223014513886 4.84222412109375,
52.61555643344044 4.769439697265625,
52.51287794429004 4.7186279296875,
52.45684622754481 4.833984375,
52.37811421553942 4.98779296875))') );

#1 outside
SELECT * FROM zones WHERE CONTAINS(geom, POINT(52.306024, 4.913726)); 
#2 **-- false positive --**
SELECT * FROM zones WHERE CONTAINS(geom, POINT(52.434471, 4.817571));
#3 inside
SELECT * FROM zones WHERE CONTAINS(geom, POINT(52.501924, 4.964426));
```

[image: Graphical representation]

I'm using MySQL 5.5 and wondered if upgrading to 5.6 will help me out here or if there might be another solution?

Comment: Yes indeed. But it returns the 'Purmerend' zone

Comment: Not sure if you're having the same problem, but upgrading to 5.6 might help, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15902320/3131147

Comment: Update: ST_CONTAINS works in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81ea2/2)

Comment: Seems like upgrading might be worth it then =) Ill try locally and see if it works

Comment: Cool! Let me know if it works out.

Comment: well 5.6 added some of the cool stuff that you find in postgis so updating will definitely be worth

Comment: Confirmed! ST_CONTAINS in MySQL 5.6 doesn't use a rect bound. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql 5.5 CONTAINS uses a bounded rect when calculating if a POINT  is within a POLYGON. MySql 5.6 ST_CONTAINS function doesn't do this and calculates the position of 2 correctly

McAdam331 proved it: `5.6 ST_CONTAINS works in this [SQL Fiddle][1]`